# Interpret significant interaction with nonsignificant main term in regression involving continuous time variable and a bounded (0-100%) variable?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, interaction, interpretation

**Scenario:**
I have data comparing the number of tree stems in 30 forest plots between two sampling years (1992 and 2012). Each plot received hurricane damage between these 2 sampling years -- this damage was coded as being 0-100% of trees felled/damaged.

I ran a **linear regression using `lm()` in R** including a centered year term, hurricane damage, and an **interaction term between them**.

I get the following output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = Count.Ha ~ I(Year - 1992) * HurrDam, data = dataset, ])

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-368.84  -69.79  -23.01   81.30  413.28 

Coefficients:
                       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)            147.3300    50.7297   2.904  0.00529 ** 
I(Year - 1992)         -17.2595     3.4007  -5.075 4.73e-06 ***
HurrDam                 -1.4680     1.6764  -0.876  0.38503    
I(Year - 1992):HurrDam   0.7634     0.1128   6.766 9.11e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 138.1 on 55 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5886,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5662 
F-statistic: 26.23 on 3 and 55 DF,  p-value: 1.15e-10
```

As you can see, Year is significant as is the interaction term, but `HurrDam` is not.
**How do I interpret this??**

- I've seen a number of posts discussing intepretation when discreet variables or even continuous non-bounded variables are involved, but I'm not sure how my inclusion of a time variable and a bounded percentage as a variable impact the way one would interpret these results.
- Note: my ultimate hypothesis I'm trying to investigate is that the number of stems did not increase with time except in plots with greatest hurricane damage.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22680/can-the-interaction-term-of-two-insignificant-coefficients-be-significant

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62921/how-to-interpret-the-significant-interaction-of-two-non-significant-main-predict

Comment: And see [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/65898/28500).  The "main effect" of a predictor involved in an interaction depends on how the _interacting_ predictor is coded. Try changing the 1992 reference year over a wide range and see how the "main effect" for `HurrDam` changes. Also, with a count outcome variable you perhaps should be using a count-based generalized linear model (Poisson, negative binomial) instead, and in either case a mixed model or robust coefficient (co)variance estimates if you are evaluating the same plots over time.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/593652/repeated-measures-anova-with-significant-interaction-effect-but-non-significant